# Posso usar "antezerésimo"?

Tags: neologismos

Estou mexendo com números ordinais (*primeiro*, *segundo*, etc.). Eu precisei me referir a 0ª, então, procurei por *anteprimeiro* e *zerésimo*; descobri que *anteprimeiro* existe e *zerésimo* provavelmente não, eu poderia usar *anteprimeiro*; mas **antezerésimo*, não.

Para os propósitos desta pergunta, se considerará “zerésimo” uma palavra formal e com o significado de “na posição 0”.

Por isso, comecei a pensar: ***antezerésimo** não existe, mas eu recentemente ouvi falar sobre formas teóricas — que são escritas com asterisco (***) — e me lembrei que várias palavras que são hoje dicionarizadas tiveram seu cunho em artigos, livro e poemas*.

Portanto, pergunto: já que *anteprimeiro* está correto e dicionarizado, posso, por analogia e se seguinte às regras morfológicas, usar *antezerésimo*? Se sim, qual a sua formalidade (considerando que *zerésimo* fosse uma palavra oficial) e como devo formatá-la; digo, devo a escrever em itálico, devo lhe informar o significado, devo escrever com * atrás de si? Se não (considerando que *zerésimo* fosse uma palavra oficial), por que não posso a usar?

P.S.: ao(s) respondedor(es), por favor, na tua(vossa) resposta, foca no parágrafo antecedente; se não fizeres(des) isso, provavelmente não aceitarei a tua(vossa) resposta. Se a minha linguagem, neste texto, parecer difícil ou se alguma palavra for desnecessária, por favor, comunicar-me, porque eu sempre tentei escrever com palavras simples, mas, hoje, estou experimentando uma linguagem um poucado diferente.

Comment: Creio que *antessegundo* seria o primeiro (antes do segundo).

Comment: Podemos saber em que contexto usas "zerésimo"? Referes "anteprimeiro", que de facto vem no dicionário -- p. ex. https://www.dicio.com.br/anteprimeiro/ -- mas o significado dado ( "Que antecede ao primeiro. Preliminar.") não parece ser um significado matemático.

Comment: @Júlio_Reis,  "anteprimeiro" = 0º e "antezerésimo" = -1º. Seria uma adaptação da palavra, se "adaptação" é a palavra".

Comment: Em alguns contextos técnicos se usa "zerésimo" com certa frequência, ainda que informalmente. Por exemplo, chama-se de "zerésima lei" a [lei zero da termodinâmica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_zero_da_termodin%C3%A2mica), e fala-se em "zerésimo elemento" em linguagens de programação com indexação de matrizes começando pelo zero. E vale notar também que existe há décadas um documento eleitoral no Brasil chamado de "zerésima", termo [já dicionarizado](https://dicionario.priberam.org/zer%C3%A9sima).

Comment: Casos de [**inconseguimento** (*frustracional*)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx_k3bSzCTo).